# How to use current company in BQL query

Tags: acumatica

I need to know how I can get the user's current company so that I can use it in the Where clause of a BQL query.  I'm not talking about the tenant "company".  I'm talking about the companies that are defined on screen CS101500.  I'm not seeing anything on the AccessInfo that seems to indicate the current Company.  The current Branch ID is there but, I need the company to which the branch belongs.

Using version 21.203

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require the creation of a custom BQL element class.

IBqlOperand - A BQL Scalar operand

IBqlCreator - A Bql elements creator that requires implementation of AppendExpression and Verify methods.

```
public class CurrentOrganization : IBqlCreator, IBqlOperand
{

    #region Methods

    #region AppendExpression

    /// <summary>
    /// Appends the SQL tree expression that corresponds to the BQL command to an SQL tree query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exp">The SQL tree expression to be appended.</param>
    /// <param name="graph">A graph instance.</param>
    /// <param name="info">The information about the BQL command.</param>
    /// <param name="selection">The fragment of the BQL command that is translated to an SQL tree expression.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool AppendExpression(ref SQLExpression exp, PXGraph graph, BqlCommandInfo info, BqlCommand.Selection selection)
    {
        if (graph == null || !info.BuildExpression)
        {
            return true;
        }

        PXMutableCollection.AddMutableItem(this);

        exp = new SQLConst(graph.BranchOrganizationID());

        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Verify

    /// <summary>
    /// No Clue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cache"></param>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="pars"></param>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public void Verify(PXCache cache, object item, List<object> pars, ref bool? result, ref object value)
    {
        value = cache.Graph.BranchOrganizationID();
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

}
```

The method call `.BranchOrganizationID()` is a `PXGraph` extension method that returns the OrganizationID from a Branch `IPrefetchable`

Calls to this prefetchable can be replaced with a BQL PXSelect :

> PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID,
> Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>.Select(...)

Example usage would be as follows :

```
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<Branch.branchID,Where<Branch.organizationID,Equal<CurrentOrganization>>>))]
```

Comment: Thanks Josh!  I suspected that I needed something like this but, there's no way I would have pieced it together.  I wasn't able to find the BranchOrganizationID() method so, the end code is slightly different.  I'll post the code shortly.

Comment: @MikeNIke Understandable as BranchOrganizationID() is a custom method that was built from a few other examples on stack overflow + Acumatica blog articles! glad my example helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code

```
 public int? GetOrganizationID(PXGraph graph, int? branchID)
 {
    int? accountID = ((Organization)OrganizationMaint.FindOrganizationByID(graph, PXAccess.GetParentOrganizationID(branchID))).BAccountID;
    return accountID;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this over.  I'm looking for a way to do this in BQL.  So, something like this:  Search<Branch.branchID, Where<Branch.organizationID, Equal<{Users Current Company}>>>

Comment: Keep in mind all data selected through BQL must be within company of the logged in user.

Comment: Sure, we're staying in the same tenant but, trying to find the currently selected Company/Organization.  See screen CS101500

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that got what I needed, per Josh's solution.  Van Hoesen for the win!!

```
public class CurrentOrganization : IBqlCreator, IBqlOperand
{
    public virtual bool AppendExpression(ref SQLExpression exp, PXGraph graph, BqlCommandInfo info, BqlCommand.Selection selection)
    {
        if ((graph == null) || (!info.BuildExpression))
            return true;

        PXMutableCollection.AddMutableItem(this);

        //exp = new SQLConst(graph.BranchOrganizationID());
        Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>.Select(graph);
        exp = new SQLConst( branch.OrganizationID);

        return true;

    }
    public void Verify(PXCache cache, object item, List<object> pars, ref bool? result, ref object value)
    {
        Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>.Select(cache.Graph);
        value = branch.OrganizationID;
        //value = cache.Graph.BranchOrganizationID();
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional Note - This isn't working for Fluent BQL.  It's complaining about "no implicit conversion to PX.Common.IImplement<PX.Data.BQL.IBqlEquitable> and PX.Common.IImplement<PX.Data.BQL.IBqlCastableTo<PX.Data.BQL.IBqlInt>>".  I'm assuming I need to implement some additional interfaces.